# How do I determine if truncation is being applied in my style through JS?

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip, truncation

I am applying truncation using CSS styles:

```
.yui-skin-sam td:not(.yui-dt-editable) .yui-dt-liner{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;        
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -moz-binding: url('ellipsis.xml#ellipsis');     
}

.yui-skin-sam td[class~=yui-dt-editable] .yui-dt-liner{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;        
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

(Sidenote: I'm not sure if this is the best way to write my CSS. This is a Firefox specific workaround since truncation on Firefox only sort-of works).

I want a tool-tip to appear over text that is truncated. How do I detect if text is truncated so that I can display a tool-tip?

Comment: I don't see any sort of ":truncated" pseudo-class in the CSS3 selector syntax, so I'm not sure how you'd tell.

Comment: in anycase css don't apply change to the dom!!! are you using the yui js lib!?

Comment: I think this solution work much better
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738117/html-text-overflow-ellipsis-detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that CSS never alter the DOM!!!

jQuery Snippets:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.link').each(function(e) {
        var link = $(this).text();
        if ( link.length > 100) {
            $(this).attr('title', link );
        }
    });
});
```

Assuming you have links

```
<a class="link" href="" >the brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</a>
```

the above code wil produce

```
    <a class="link" href="" title="the brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" >
     the brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
    </a>
```

the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` property will do the rest as you know!

---

**GOING AHEAD:**

there is a small plugin here

*I wanted to be able to use this feature in all browsers, so I wrote a small jQuery plugin in order to support Firefox. To use, just call ellipsis() on a jQuery object. For example:*

```
$("span").ellipsis();
```

> - http://ajaxian.com/archives/text-overflow-for-firefox-via-jquery

Answer (score 19):

The question is old and was answered.

However to apply the solution given by @aSeptik you need to know in advance how many characters fits into the container, or to use a jQuery plugin.

I arrived to the same issue, and today the solution is very simple: use the `clientWith` and `scrollWidth` properties.

The content is truncated if `elem.scrollWidth > elem.clientWidth`.

Here is the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollWidth

And a example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/diegof79/de9xsn4b/

Comment: And I thought I'll have manually calculate the size of my component... Nice!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks for sharing it