# How to test text-overflow element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, overflow, selenium-chromedriver

when the text attribute is set to

```
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

the overflowed text will be displayed as "`XX...`" (see screenshot for more )
how can I find the overflowed `text/element` in webdriver?

thanks in advance

[Screenshot of Overflowed text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4ZWR.jpg)

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: I use xpath "//span[string-length(text()) > 2]" to find the elements which text length > 2. however, I'm testing multi-language app and " > x" rule didn't always apply to other languages. so I'm wondering if there is any better way to find the overflowed elements

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest/best way to do this is to use the JS `innerText` property, e.g.

```
driver.findElement(lcoator).getAttribute("innerText");
```

If I remember correctly, some browsers use `textContent` instead.

```
driver.findElement(lcoator).getAttribute("textContent");
```

This should get you the full text inside that element.

You could also pull `innerHTML` and parse it (if needed) or remove the `text-overflow` style from the element but these are harder/more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah, I'm able to get the innerText using getAttribute("innerText"), but the extracted text is full text, I still don't know if they are overflowed or not...  I'm testing multi-language app, if I use "text() > x" to check if the text is overflowed then I need to use different x for different language... is there any way to know if the text is overflowed or not?

Comment: I don't guess I understand what you are testing. Can't you just check if the last character is an ellipsis and then check innerText and make sure the length is not the same as the overflowed text? It sounds like you are going to end up verifying that the CSS attribute is working.

Answer (score -1):

In case you have jQuery available in your project, you can write your own selector:

```
$.expr[':'].truncated = function (e) {
  // you *might* want to check if css property "text-overflow"
  // is set to "ellipsis" as well, to filter other truncations:
  return e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth;
};
```

and go from there:

```
items = $('.your-selector:truncated');
```

(heavily based on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7738117/3890673))

Comment: ...like `$(e).css('text-overflow') === 'ellipsis'`