# Angular - How to know if select text cut off?

Tags: angular, select

I have selects that sometimes have a long string in it and sometimes it cut off, in that cases I want to put a tooltip on them but I don't want to show the tooltip if the text is fully showed inside the select.

Is there any validation to this using Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it.
If you are using a vanilla select, you can try the following.
Worked for me perfectly.
The key is to wrap your `<option>` with a `<span>` to get the texts actual pixel width

Html:

```
<select id="select" (change)="debug()" style="max-width:200px">
  <option>
    <span>
        Blalalalalalalalallalaalalalalalalalallaallalalalalaal
    </span>
  </option>
  <option>
    <span>
        Blalalallalalalalalalalalalallaal
    </span>
  </option>
  <option>
    <span>
        Blalalalalala
    </span>
  </option>
</select>
```

TS:

```
  debug() {
    const el = document.querySelector('#select');
    for (let i = 0; i < el['options'].length; i++) {
      if (this.isEllipsisActive(el['options'][i])) {
        console.log('cause offset', el['options'][i]);
      }
    }
  }
  isEllipsisActive(e) {
    if (e.children[0].scrollWidth > document.querySelector('#select').scrollWidth) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: My problem isn't the tooltip but how to know if the text in my select is cutted off or not. I don't want to show a tooltip when the content is all visible to the user

Comment: Do you use Jquery?

Comment: found out how to indicate if the select has an offset but not wich option is causing it.

Comment: Hey, got it. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't use the selector but your answer helped me finding the width for the text and the select

Answer (score 0):

From: [HTML text-overflow ellipsis detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738117/html-text-overflow-ellipsis-detection)

You could try using this:

```
function isEllipsisActive(e) {
     return (e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth);
}
```

Comment: Didn't work on Angular, offsetWidth and scrollWidth came out as undefined... going to check what comes in the event to check if I can get it work someway