# Ag-grid tooltip above ellipsis text only

Tags: javascript, angular6, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I'm using the enterprise [ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com) version in my project.
I found tooltip supporting under the box and make as follows:

```
columnDefs = [
{
    headerName: 'USER NAME',
    field: 'userName',
    sortingOrder: ['asc', 'desc'],
    filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
    filterParams: {newRowsAction: "keep"},
    floatingFilterComponentParams: {suppressFilterButton: true},
    suppressMenu: true,
    tooltip: (t: any) => { return t.value; }
}, //...
];
```

Tooltip works fine and shows above every cell of the '*userName*' column in my grid.
Is it possible to show tooltip above headers/cells if a text is ellipsis only?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have the exact same question.

Comment: I'm also have same requirement

Comment: Same here .. did u find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In case of someone is checking this question, maybe a solution could be use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738117/html-text-overflow-ellipsis-detection) to detect if ellipsis is showing.

Then do something like this:

```
if (ellipsisIsShowing())
   return t.value;
else 
  return; //no tooltip will be shown
```

Answer (score 0):

In continuation from @cacatua_box answer here my solution. Only cell level.

```
    ...
    defaultColDef: {
      sortable: true,
      filter: true,
      resizable: true,
      suppressMovable: true,
      tooltipComponent: CustomTooltip,
    },
```

```
class CustomTooltip {
  eGui: HTMLDivElement

  init(params: ITooltipParams) {
    this.eGui = document.createElement('div')
    this.eGui.innerHTML = params.value

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
    // @ts-ignore
    const cell = params.api.rowRenderer.rowCtrlsByRowIndex[params.rowIndex]?.centerGui.element.querySelector(`[col-id='${params.column.colId}']`) // prettier-ignore

    this.eGui.style.display = cell?.scrollWidth > cell?.offsetWidth || params.location === 'header' ? 'block' : 'none'
  }

  getGui() {
    return this.eGui
  }
}
```