# How do I test whether the inner text of an element has wrapped onto multiple lines?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, responsive-design

Certain elements of my web page should never wrap their inner text onto multiple lines, no matter how narrow the browser window is. I would like to know how to write a test to check that the inner text of an element has not wrapped onto multiple lines.

## My Minimal Reproducible Example

### PageToTest.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Page to test</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
          rel="stylesheet" 
          integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" 
          crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Page to test</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="menu" class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                <div>Menu option 1</div>
                <div>Menu option 2</div>
                <div>Menu option 3</div>
                <div>Menu option 4</div>
                <div>Menu option 5</div>
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="col-lg-11 col-md-10 col-sm-9">
                <!-- some random text from https://www.lipsum.com just to take up horizontal space -->
                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque consequat ligula turpis, sit amet luctus neque iaculis a. Nunc consectetur nulla ut sapien pellentesque, quis lobortis odio imperdiet. Maecenas mollis tortor non nulla malesuada dictum. Quisque ultricies a sem at fermentum. Aenean risus lorem, sodales vitae porta non, pharetra a velit. Vivamus semper elit vitae massa pellentesque, ut viverra enim mollis. Fusce at odio vulputate, suscipit arcu vel, imperdiet mauris. Ut at posuere est. Proin consequat quis nisl ut lobortis. Curabitur quam lacus, dictum at leo volutpat, maximus aliquet eros. Fusce tincidunt tristique purus in suscipit. Aliquam at scelerisque ante, sit amet iaculis metus. Aenean feugiat tellus ipsum, a sodales dolor commodo eget. Phasellus eu bibendum leo, in pulvinar justo.</div>
                <div>Integer semper laoreet libero non hendrerit. Nullam id dui consequat neque suscipit tristique mattis nec libero. Donec vestibulum pharetra varius. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus ac diam nisi. Suspendisse bibendum, elit eu ultrices porttitor, orci mauris maximus lorem, sed rutrum lacus nisi feugiat elit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus vulputate varius tellus in tempor. Maecenas pretium felis quis nisi dictum, ut pulvinar sapien vestibulum. Ut in scelerisque est, id dapibus lorem. Nullam consectetur mauris et finibus porta. Etiam interdum venenatis sem vitae gravida. Donec porta tellus risus, et hendrerit arcu mattis nec.</div>
                <div>Curabitur gravida fringilla neque nec eleifend. Suspendisse nisi est, mollis vitae fringilla in, lobortis a tellus. Sed feugiat ex vel nibh laoreet gravida. Curabitur quis malesuada tortor. In dictum condimentum volutpat. Quisque ultrices mauris et sollicitudin rhoncus. Praesent non mauris sed est eleifend interdum eget et mauris. Mauris vitae sollicitudin neque.</div>
                <div>Duis ut nulla dignissim, dictum lectus ut, vehicula orci. Curabitur tincidunt imperdiet magna. Pellentesque et nulla id nunc malesuada suscipit. Vivamus ultrices, nunc quis consequat faucibus, est augue vehicula ligula, nec sodales elit elit vel tortor. Suspendisse ac neque accumsan, consequat augue sed, dignissim nibh. Duis nisl massa, semper vitae blandit id, vestibulum eget orci. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec leo massa, suscipit ut sodales in, auctor sit amet ex.</div>
                <div>Nam magna libero, varius ac dui id, finibus faucibus mauris. Maecenas mattis tincidunt tortor, quis ultricies elit efficitur sed. Cras a turpis sit amet dolor volutpat pellentesque at sed leo. Aliquam quis varius eros, vel tristique dolor. Nunc sit amet urna volutpat, accumsan nunc et, mattis enim. Sed vehicula blandit sollicitudin. Mauris consequat sem ut efficitur lacinia. Cras at diam et ipsum feugiat lacinia sed sed mauris. Nullam dignissim neque vitae interdum mattis. Vestibulum sollicitudin ex ex, vitae cursus nisi dapibus eget. Pellentesque bibendum commodo pretium.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
            integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" 
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### What's wrong?

As I reduce the width of the browser window, the text of the menu items down the left hand side start to wrap onto multiple lines, changing from ...

```
Menu option 1
```

... to ...

```
Menu option
1
```

... to ...

```
Menu
option 1
```

... and eventually ...

```
Menu
option
1
```

... until Bootstrap steps in and stacks `#menu` above `#content`.

I don't want the text of those menu items to wrap, I want the column they're contained in to grow so that it's always wide enough to display them without wrapping. Or maybe the font size could shrink, or maybe the whole menu could hide itself when the browser window isn't wide enough to display both the menu and the content, or some other solution.

But my question isn't about how to stop the text from wrapping, but **how to write a test to check whether or not it's wrapping**.

## What I've tried

### Feature file

(I'm using SpecFlow in this project, but it's not really a SpecFlow question)

```
Feature: PageToTest

@tag1
Scenario Outline: Left hand menu does not word wrap
    Given I am on the page to test
    When I resize the browser width to <pixels> pixels
    Then The text in the left hand menu does not wrap onto multiple lines

    Examples: 
    | pixels |
    | 1920   |
    | 1900   |
    | 1800   |
    | 1700   |
    | 1600   |
    | 1500   |
    | 1400   |
    | 1300   |
    | 1200   |
    | 1100   |
    | 1000   |
    | 900    |
    | 800    |
    | 700    |
    | 600    |
    | 500    |
    | 400    |
```

### Step definitions / hooks

```
    using System.Drawing;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
    using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

    [Binding]
    public class TestSteps
    {
        private readonly IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        [Given(@"I am on the page to test")]
        public void GivenIAmOnThePageToTest()
        {
            // The HTML file is in my test project's root folder with
            // "Copy to output directory" set to "always"
            var url = $"file://{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/PageToTest.html";
            this.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        }

        [When(@"I resize the browser width to (.*) pixels")]
        public void WhenIResizeTheBrowserWidthToPixelsPixels(int width)
        {
            var currentSize = this.driver.Manage().Window.Size;
            this.driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(width, currentSize.Height);
        }

        [Then(@"The text in the left hand menu does not wrap onto multiple lines")]
        public void ThenTheTextInTheLeftHandMenuDoesNotWrapOntoMultipleLines()
        {
            var menuOptions = this.driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#menu div"));
            foreach (var menuOption in menuOptions)
            {
                // This doesn't build, but hopefully you understand what I'm after
                // Assert.False(menuOption.InnerTextHasWrappedOntoMultipleLines);
            }
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void AfterScenario()
        {
            if (this.driver != null)
            {
                this.driver.Quit();
                this.driver.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

The logic for launching the browser, navigating to the page, and setting the browser window width to the desired number of pixels all seems to be working fine. But I'm at a loss as to how to implement the `ThenTheTextInTheLeftHandMenuDoesNotWrapOntoMultipleLines` method. `IWebElement` doesn't have a `InnerTextHasWrappedOntoMultipleLines` property, nor any other property or method which does what I'm looking for, as far as I can tell from the documentation. I'm hoping that there's a type that I can cast `IWebElement` to which has such a property or method, or maybe a package with an extension method which does this. Or maybe Selenium offers another way of achieving this which I just haven't thought of.

Comment: Would something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169520/how-can-i-check-whether-line-clamp-is-enabled) work for you ?

Comment: Possibly. It's using client-side JavaScript though, so I'd need to dynamically add something into the DOM to indicate to Selenium whether the text has wrapped, which feels a bit hacky. I'll have a play with the idea though and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @ChristineTreacy for drawing my attention to [How can I check whether line-clamp is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52169520/16563198), which didn't answer my question but did send me down a line of thought which led to this answer.

This JavaScript function will tell us whether the element with a given ID has wrapped:

```
/**
 * Determines whether the text in the supplied element has wrapped onto multiple lines.
 * @param {string} id ID of the element to test.
 * @returns {boolean} True if the text in the element has wrapped, otherwise false.
 */
function hasWrapped(id) {
    // Get the element we want to test for wrapped text
    let jQueryElement = $(`#${id}`);

    // This gives us the height the element would have if the text were on a single line
    const cssLineHeight = jQueryElement.css('line-height').replace('px', '');

    // This gives us the actual height of the element
    const actualHeight = jQueryElement.height();

    // If the actual height is greater than the line height then the text has wrapped.
    return actualHeight > cssLineHeight;
}
```

I couldn't seem to call this function from my test step, but putting the code into a private string in my test class seemed to work (I've never tried executing JavaScript from a Selenium test before so there may be cleaner ways of doing this).

```
        private readonly string hasWrappedScript = @"
const jQueryElement = $('#{0}');
const cssLineHeight = jQueryElement.css('line-height').replace('px', '');
const actualHeight = jQueryElement.height();
return actualHeight > cssLineHeight;
";
```

The test step method now looks like this:

```
[Then(@"The text in the left hand menu does not wrap onto multiple lines")]
public void ThenTheTextInTheLeftHandMenuDoesNotWrapOntoMultipleLines()
{
    var menuItems = this.driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#menu div"));
    var failures = new List<string>();
    foreach (var menuItem in menuItems)
    {
        var id = menuItem.GetAttribute("id");
        var script = string.Format(this.hasWrappedScript, id);

        // ExecuteJavaScript extension method is in the OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions
        // namespace in the Selenium.Support NuGet package.
        var hasWrapped = this.driver.ExecuteJavaScript<bool>(script);
        if (hasWrapped)
        {
            failures.Add(id);
        }
    }

    if (failures.Count > 0)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder("The following elements have wrapped incorrectly: ");
        foreach (var f in failures)
        {
            sb.Append($"{f} ");
        }

        // Assert.Fail requires xunit 2.4.2 or later
        Assert.Fail(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

So the test will fail if the text in any of the elements in the `menuItems` collection wraps, and will list the IDs of any which have wrapped in the failure message.