# How to truncate block text and have a trailing link

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scss-mixins

I am attempting to have truncating block of text, using ellipses, that can expand and collapse using a button. This project uses React.

Individually I can get the block text to truncate correctly with ellipses and a coworker has the link in the correct place using some relative positioning. Currently, the 'View More' button sits on top of the ellipses and all attempts to include it in the text block itself results in the truncation of the button text, which I do not want. I need a way to truncate the text without truncating the button, while still having it look like it is inline.

[image: Block text with truncation.]

[image: Block text with 'View More' button]

I am currently using the CSS code below to get my current results. I have tried a variety of positioning and HTML movement but cannot find a way to get it how I want.

```css
.all-text {
    @include typ-body-1-16-regular;
    margin-bottom: calc(1.5 * #{$default-padding});

    @include xs-mobile {
      @include typ-body-2-14-regular;
      text-align: left;
    }

    & .overflow {
      @include max-width-for-ingreients;
      display: block;

      @include xs-mobile {
        text-overflow: clip;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      }
    }

    & .text-expander {
      display: none;
      text-decoration: underline;

      @include xs-mobile {
        display: initial;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: $white;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        top: -18px;

        &.expanded {
          top: 0px;
          float: revert;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
          <div className={styles['all-text']}>
            <span
              className={`${isExpanded ? '' : styles['overflow']}`}
            >
              <b>{t('subtitle')}&nbsp;</b>
              {ingredients}
              {isExpanded && expander}
            </span>
            {!isExpanded && expander}
          </div>
```

How do I truncate this block text with ellipses and still have a trailing link inline?

Comment: I don't know think there is an easy way to achieve what you want. I would suggest that you could put the button outside the text OR set the opacity of the button so that the text can also be seen.

Comment: This isn't related to React, and is a pure CSS question. By your desired-outcome photo, you could absolute-position a link to `bottom:0` & `right:0` (LTR text) and have it shown on hover.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I am trying to comply with a designer right now. I may have to come back to them and tell them the design needs to change.

Answer (score 1):

I advise a combination of both including the link in the truncated text and also adding the link as a stand-alone component, which will only be rendered if the text is truncated.

To know if the text is truncated, in real-time, you can follow my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67455839/104380).

So, as long as the text fits the container, the link is shown (at the end I understand), and if the text doesn't fit the container, conditionally render the link (extra) component.

If the text is truncated, completely hide the link (`display:none`) and measure the link's width and create a `shape-outside` over the text so it would be truncated exactly before the link was at, and then render your link component over the text, right after the 3-dots.

Make sure the `shape-outside` leaves enough space for the 3-dots + link

Comment: +1 this is good advice for solving the problem. BUT... If it were me... I would suggest another finding another way of implementing this that is less code heavy. IMO it is a huge win (in terms of maintenance costs) to minimize your code base to what is essential to the business.