# Add extra space at the end of the ellipsis in a multiline truncated text

Tags: css

Assume an LTR text that can be truncated, if the text exceeds its parent's height.

I would like to use `shape-outside` (or any better way) to reserve a space at the **end** of the truncated text

Ideal solution would be pure-CSS

(assume I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169520/how-can-i-check-whether-line-clamp-is-enabled/67455839#67455839) when is the text being truncated so I would add a space then)

#### Desired outcome:

[image]

#### Code:

```css
p {
  font: 20px Arial;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px dashed silver;  
  
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla</p>
```

I need this to be able to solve a more complex product-design problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may give a try with an extra tag and a pseudo, both floatting . the pseudo pushing down this extra element that you can size.

example

```css
p {
  font: 20px Arial;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px dashed silver;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p:before {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  height: 2.4em;
}

p i {
  clear: both;
  float: right;
  width: 180px;
  height: 1em;
  background: silver/* see me */
}
```

```html
<p><i></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla</p>
```

With shape-outside and css var() to help tuning it, it could be :

```css
p {
  --shapeH: 2.6em;
  --shapeW: 180px;
  font: 20px Arial;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px dashed silver;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p:before {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  height: 3.6em;
  width: 100%;
  shape-outside: polygon(100% var(--shapeH), 100% 0, 100% var(--shapeH), 100% 100%, calc(100% - var(--shapeW)) 100%, calc(100% - var(--shapeW)) var(--shapeH));
  
  /* show that shape */
  background:blue;
  clip-path: polygon(100% var(--shapeH), 100% 0, 100% var(--shapeH), 100% 100%, calc(100% - var(--shapeW)) 100%, calc(100% - var(--shapeW)) var(--shapeH));
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla</p>
```