# Correct way to check line-clamp for vue compent

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

This question perfectly fits what I am trying to do, check if the text is truncated or not [How can I check whether line-clamp is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169520/how-can-i-check-whether-line-clamp-is-enabled).  I am aware this is not correct, I would really appreciate any direction to get this working.

SCRIPT

```
const isExpanded = ref(true);
```

```
const isTextTruncated = ref(true);
```

```
 const toggleCta = computed(() =>   isExpanded.value ? 'show' : 'hide' )
```

```
const information = ref(true);
```

```
const isTextTruncated = computed(() => {
  const textLineCount = information.getClientRects().length;
  const lineClampValue = information.css('-webkit-line-clamp');
  if (textLineCount > lineClampValue) {
    return true
  }
})
```

TEMPLATE

```
<div ref="information" :class="isExpanded ? 'truncate': ''">
  {{ data?.information }}
</div>
<span
  v-if="isTextTruncated"
  @click="isExpanded = !isExpanded"
>
  {{ toggleCta }}
</span>
```

STYLE

```
.truncate {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

I tried [How can I check whether line-clamp is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169520/how-can-i-check-whether-line-clamp-is-enabled)

Answer (score 0):

In your Vue.js code, you're trying to check whether the -webkit-line-clamp CSS property is enabled on an element. You're on the right track, but there are a few issues in your code that need to be addressed.

1. information should be a reference to the DOM element, not a boolean value. You can use ref to reference the DOM element.
2. You are trying to access the -webkit-line-clamp property using information.css ('-webkit-line-clamp'), but this is not the correct way to get the value of a CSS property in Vue.js. You should use window.getComputedStyle to access the computed style of an element.

Try to this

Script

```
const isExpanded = ref(true);
const information = ref(null); // Initialize to null
const isTextTruncated = ref(false);

const toggleCta = computed(() => isExpanded.value ? 'show' : 'hide');

watch(information, () => {
  // Use watch to monitor changes in the 'information' ref
  const element = information.value;
  if (element) {
    const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    const lineClampValue = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('-webkit-line-clamp');
    const textLineCount = element.getClientRects().length;
    isTextTruncated.value = textLineCount > lineClampValue;
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<div ref="information" :class="isExpanded ? 'truncate' : ''">
  {{ data?.information }}
</div>
<span
  v-if="isTextTruncated"
  @click="isExpanded = !isExpanded"
>
  {{ toggleCta }}
</span>
```

Comment: This is excellent thank you! Really helpful explanation. I have a TS error in this line `const textLineCount = element.getClientRects().length;` Property 'getClientRects' does not exist on type 'never'.

Comment: Just an update, setting `const information = ref();` removes this error.

Comment: This would be perfect, the only issue I now face is `textLineCount` always returns 0