# How to activate tooltip when ellipsis is activated using a directive in angular 5?

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-directive

I have the following template with a "dotdotdot" css class which add
ellipsis on overflow correctly.

```
<div class="dotdotdot">{{data.trip.name}}</div>
```

What I'm trying to do here is to implement a directive which add a tooltip when
the ellipsis is activated only.

Here is the current code from the directive:

```
import { Directive, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '.dotdotdot'
})
export class DotdotdotDirective implements OnInit {

  private el: HTMLElement;
  constructor(elRef: ElementRef) {
    this.el = elRef.nativeElement;
}

ngOnInit() {           
         if (this.isEllipsisActive(this.el)) {   
            // TODO add title attribute to the div with value from text         
            $(this.el).tooltip();     
         }         
}

isEllipsisActive(e) {
     return (e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth);
}

}
```

I have two problems in the code above:

1. isEllipsisActive is not working, I need the way to identified the ellipsis.
2. I need to know how to add title or [title] attribute dynamically 
   from $(this.el). The value is the text from the div.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML text-overflow ellipsis detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738117/html-text-overflow-ellipsis-detection)

Comment: It works without jQuery. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-problem-databinding-svyhec).

Comment: A bit more robust answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55106043/540352). It works with `ngAfterViewChecked` so no `setTimeout` required + also clears the title if it is not necessary anymore when the `innerText` changes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create this directive:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output } from 

'@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[isEllipsisActive]'
})
export class IsEllipsisActiveDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
      if(element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth){
        element.title = element.innerHTML;
      }
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

take a look on this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjmg7m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fis-ellipsis-active.directive.ts

Comment: would this work for Mobile or I have to implement other way ?

Answer (score 8):

Great answer by ofir - Here's a modified version that will work if text changes after initialization.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[isEllipsisActive]'
})

export class isEllipsisActiveDirective {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('mouseenter')
  onMouseEnter(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
      if (element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth) {
        element.title = element.textContent;
      }
      else if (element.title) element.removeAttribute('title'); 
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

Comment: The setTimeout isn't necessary but great idea. Helped me out a lot.

Comment: there should be a little bit different solution if you want to show it with delay on each hover, other than that, thank you for this.


btw, it works strangely with kendo slider for angular. when I hover - code works, but title shows only when I do mousemove again (looks like it needs to recalculate UI based on mouse movement or something). Cant defeat it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  isEllipsisActive(e: HTMLElement): boolean {
    return e ? (e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth) : false;
  }
```

```html
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-title #galleryTitle [matTooltip]="gallery.name"
        [matTooltipDisabled]="!isEllipsisActive(galleryTitle)">
        {{gallery.name}}
    </mat-card-title>
<mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the disableTooltip property, and make a function for return if disable or not.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-smart-tooltip