# Ellipsis directive with title

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have an Angular directive that adds styling `text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;` in `ngOnInit` and then looks something like this:

```
@Directive({ selector: 'ellipsis' })
class EllipsisDirective {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const el: HTMLElement = this.el.nativeElement;
    if (el.offsetWidth < el.scrollWidth) {
      el.setAttribute('title', el.innerText);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage: `<div ellipsis>Some Very Long Text Here</div>`

**The problem:**
On some pages, the layout/components do not change on a 'navigate', only the data does. Currently the directive does not pick up the difference in `el.innerText` and thus keeps the old `.title` property.

I've also tried using an `Input()` and work with with `ngOnChanges()`. I'd prefer to not use an input though.

I can make it work with the input and a `setTimeout` but that can hardly be the way to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480394/how-to-activate-tooltip-when-ellipsis-is-activated-using-a-directive-in-angular?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess one should've started with the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). The answer is using the `AfterViewChecked` lifecycle event.

> **AfterViewChecked**
>   Respond after Angular checks the content projected into the directive/component.
>
> Called after the ngAfterContentInit() and every subsequent ngDoCheck().

```
@Directive({ selector: '[appEllipsis]' })
export class EllipsisDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
  private get hasOverflow(): boolean {
    const el: HTMLElement = this.el.nativeElement;
    return el.offsetWidth < el.scrollWidth;
  }

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // class overflow: text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;
    this.el.nativeElement.classList.add('overflow');
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    const isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
    if (isBrowser) {
      if (this.hasOverflow) {
        this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('title', this.el.nativeElement.innerText);
      } else {
        this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('title', '');
      }
    }
  }
}
```