# Is there a css selector like :is-showing-ellipsis?

Tags: css, text, formatting, ellipsis

I would like to make a question mark icon appear after any `<span>` that has `text-overflow:ellipsis` and is currently showing the dots. **Is there a way to achieve this?**

Comment: short answer: no but depending on your html structure we can find workarounds and hacks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738117/html-text-overflow-ellipsis-detection You could use jquery?

Comment: Is not a good practice check a property in order to change some element. The best way is to use a class to identify which `<span>` will have a question mark icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Text overflow string

```
.overflow-string {
  text-overflow: "..?";
}
```

But it only works on Firefox 9

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow