# HTML, how to get exact text in viewport (not just p tags that overlap with clientRect)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, dom

I would like to obtain the text that is currently on screen.
This should be the exact text that is visible, independent of html tag boundaries. Getting `<p>` tags that are partially visible is not good enough.

**Example input:**

```
<p>
AAAAAAA (lots of text, above current viewport)
BBBBBBB (lots of text, inside current viewport)
</p>
<p>
CCCCCCC (lots of text, inside current viewport)
DDDDDDD (lots of text, below current viewport)
</p>
```

**Desired output:**

```
BBBBBBBCCCCCCC
```

**Solution attempt:**

I could only find out how to do visibility checks on the level of dom elements. So my solution attempt is to add lots of dummy elements:

```
<p>
<span>A</span><span>A</span><span>A</span><span>A</span><span>A</span><span>A</span>
</p>
```

At this point, my question becomes a duplicate of this one: [How can I tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/7557433#7557433)

It is then simple to iterate through dom elements, check whether they are visible and use their text content if yes.

The problem is that the text is really long and I would like to have visibility checks on the level of individual words. I've created a simple test case: a single p tag with 1000 spans inside. Each span has a small bit of random text. On my old android, scrolling is super laggy.

Comment: So, you question (in contrast with the potential duplicate you mentioned) is "How can I tell what portion of the text of a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?"

Comment: Here is another question that is related (not a duplicate). The accepted solution is hacky (even by the author's standards), and falls short of what you are trying to do by a lot. I'm guessing there is no answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738117/html-text-overflow-ellipsis-detection