# Show more based on height in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have successfully implemented the show more/show less. My problem is that I want to achieve it based on the number of lines or height of the screen. I don't want it to be based on number of characters since it would look bad on certain screens. like kinda cut on larger screen while too long on small screens.

Pls check my codesandbox here
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-86w29?file=/Wrapper.js)

```
  <DescriptionText>
    {isShowMore ? text.slice(0, 300) : text}
  </DescriptionText>
  {text && text.length > 300 && (
    <ShowMoreText onClick={toggleReadMore}>
      {isShowMore ? "Show more..." : "Show less"}
    </ShowMoreText>
  )}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `styled-components` I've found a great utility package for it: [polished.js](https://polished.js.org/)

You would be looking for the [ellipsis](https://polished.js.org/docs/#ellipsis) utility.

> **ellipsis**
>
> CSS to represent truncated text with an ellipsis. You can optionally
> pass a max-width and number of lines before truncating.
>
> ```
> ellipsis(width: (string? | number?)?, lines: number): Styles
> ```

Example: Display up to 3 lines when show more, otherwise full text.

```
import { ellipsis } from 'polished';

...

const DescriptionText = styled.div`
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  ${({ showMore }) => showMore && ellipsis(undefined, 3)}
`;

...

const Description = () => {
  const [isShowMore, setIsShowMore] = useState(true);
  const toggleReadMore = () => setIsShowMore(show => !show);

  return (
    <MainContainer>
      <TitleText>Description</TitleText>
      <DescriptionText showMore={isShowMore}>{text}</DescriptionText>
      <ShowMoreText onClick={toggleReadMore}>
        {isShowMore ? "Show more..." : "Show less"}
      </ShowMoreText>
    </MainContainer>
  );
};
```

[image] [image]

[image: Edit show-more-based-on-height-in-react]

You seem to have mentioned in another answer that you don't want to add any new dependencies, so here is the CSS that is applied via the `ellipsis` utility. Though, I'd still recommend adding `polished` to your project if you can as it has *many* useful styling utilities I've found fairly invaluable.

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const DescriptionText = styled.div`
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  ${({ showMore }) =>
    showMore &&
    css`
      display: -webkit-box;
      max-width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: normal;
      word-wrap: normal;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    `}
`;
```

To handle different screen sizes/responsiveness you can use media queries and specify a different number of lines you want to initially display.

Comment: Hi @Drew Reese. If there are few texts, how could you hide the `Show more...`? There will be no sense to show `Show more` if there is very little texts. Thank you.

Comment: @Joseph I found a some SO posts regarding testing the rendered content width to compute if an overflow is occurring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64689074/how-to-check-if-text-is-truncated-by-css-using-javascript, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738117/html-text-overflow-ellipsis-detection. The jquery answer seemed promising but it usually not a good idea to mix jquery with React, but I think in this case it might be ok since jquery isn't being used to update anything React is rendering. (*I tried converting the logic over to React, got close*).

Comment: @Joseph I'll tinker around a bit more when I have time.

Answer (score -1):

How about `window.innerHeight < minHeight`? This means you need to define `minHeight`

```js
const text = `Lorem ipsum .....`; //
let _shouldTruncate = null;
const minHeight = 750;
const Description = () => {
  const descTextEl = useRef(null);
  const [isShowMore, setIsShowMore] = useState(true);
  const toggleReadMore = () => {
    setIsShowMore(!isShowMore);
  };
  const [txtVal, setTxtVal] = useState(""); //save value to state
  //updates `txtVal` on change of `isShowMore`
  useEffect(() => {
    if (_shouldTruncate === null) {
      _shouldTruncate = window.innerHeight < minHeight;
    }
    setTxtVal(_shouldTruncate && isShowMore ? text.slice(0, 300) : text);
  }, [txtVal, isShowMore]);

  return (
    <MainContainer>
      <TitleText>Description</TitleText>
      <DescriptionText ref={descTextEl}>{txtVal}</DescriptionText>
      {_shouldTruncate && (
        <ShowMoreText onClick={toggleReadMore}>
          {isShowMore ? "Show more..." : "Show less"}
        </ShowMoreText>
      )}
    </MainContainer>
  );
};
```

**UPDATE:**

Since you wanted to get the number of lines, you might need to calculate it using this logic from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/783936/7291240):

```
function countLines() {
   var el = document.getElementById('content');
   var divHeight = el.offsetHeight
   var lineHeight = parseInt(el.style.lineHeight);
   //or use computed lineHeight: 
   //var lineHeight = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue("lineHeight");
   var lines = divHeight / lineHeight;
   alert("Lines: " + lines);
}
```

**Update:**

You need to import `ReactDom` to calculate the style.

[Code Sandbox using `window.innerHeight`](https://codesandbox.io/s/show-more-button-based-on-windowinnerheight-q1ze1)

[Code Sandbox based on number of lines](https://codesandbox.io/s/show-more-button-based-on-number-of-lines-0rgmm?file=/Wrapper.js)

Comment: This is not what I wanted. I want to revise the function that it shouldnt count the number of characters, I want it to be based on the number of lines. It might be several lines on mobile devices BUT only few lines on desktop/laptop, thats why.

Comment: the logic is there. save the text in the state and modify it according to your rules. use `useEffect` so you can get the reference to the `HTMLDivElement`.

Comment: @Joseph, posted updated codesandbox. Took some time. Lucky I currently don't have anything to do. ;)

Comment: You probably might need to add a listener on window's `resize` but you take the wheel man.