# Display adjacent element when hovering over text that has ellipsis activated

Tags: html, css

Given two adjacent `<p>` elements, is it possible using a pure CSS solution to display the second `<p>` element if text ellipsis is activated on the first one and it's being hovered over?

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
}

.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ellipsis + p {
  display: none;
}

.ellipsis:hover + p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p class="ellipsis">Long text that might overflow and produce an ellipsis</p>
    <p>Text that shows on ellipsis hover</p>
</div>
```

Here's a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qmugdshn/) of the problem if needed

e.g. If the `container` is set to 400px, hovering over the first `<p>` element should **not** display the second `<p>` element

Comment: What are you trying here? "is it possible using a pure CSS solution to display the second <p> element if text ellipsis is activated on the first one and it's being hovered over", "If the container is set to 400px, hovering over the first <p> element should not display the second <p> element" two opposite statements.

Comment: If the container width is 400px, then text ellipsis won't be activated and hovering over the first `<p>` element shouldn't display the second one. But given a container width of 200px, then ellipsis will be activated and it should happen.

Comment: If the point is to show the whole text of the first element, with the second element, you could keep it very simple: Just have one element with ellipsis and on hovering over that element change the text-overflow to normal.

Comment: You can not create a hover "trigger" that works _only_ when those three dots are hovered, no.

Comment: I think you need to use JavaScript to add that functionality. [Here is a solution using JavaScript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738117/html-text-overflow-ellipsis-detection)

Comment: Yeah, looks like a JS solution is the only way to go about this. I don't want to display the full text on hover but an entirely separate element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution works for you. In this case when you hover the text will be displayed. All you need to achieve this is to make the text wrap on hover, and be displayed in multiple lines `white-space: normal;`.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
}

.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ellipsis:hover {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p class="ellipsis">Long text that might overflow and produce an ellipsis. Text that shows on ellipsis hover.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this isn't what I'm looking for