# When a slick grid header is truncated

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Is there any way to know when a column header label is being truncated?

Being asked when loading if the label is truncated to change the label to a configured abbreviation but I dont know if we can know when a header is being truncated.

Comment: I guess you might get an answer from someone who has encountered this exact situation but for the rest of us, there’s nowhere near enough to go on.  Feel like adding a sample?

Comment: Not a Slickgrid issue, but an HTML one. You can get and test the header cells, say using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935483/how-do-i-determine-if-truncation-is-being-applied-in-my-style-through-js

Comment: I'm working on a column autosize feature, it would be easy enough to have a per-column flag indicating truncation, I'll add that to it.